# use find command in bash file

Tags: find, cron

I am using this script in my Linux machine to find all files that were modified yesterday:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/*/domains/*/public_html/  -name "*.php" -mtime -1 | while read line; do
echo "$line"
done
```

The script works as expected when I run it manually but fails with the error below if I run it from `cron`:

```
find: `/home/*/domains/*/public_html/': No such file or directory
```

distribution: Centos 5

cron:

```
#DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. Change through DirectAdmin
MAILTO=MYMAIL@gmail.com
*/1 * * * * bash /home/admin/check_phpfile_changed.sh
```

single quotes not work

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /home/*/domains/*/public_html/`?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackexchange. You could post the content of what you wrote in the crontab to make this a better question.

Comment: This won't be causing the problem but what's the point of the `while` loop? `find` already prints its output by default, the `while` isn't doing anything useful and might cause problems if your file names contain newlines. Just remove it.

Comment: Also, pelase [edit] your question and tell us i) what distribution you are using; ii) what `cron` implementation; iii) show us the relevant crontab line; Are you maybe putting `/home/*/domains/*/public_html/` in single quotes?

Comment: Try to add `SHELL=/bin/bash` to the cron(tab).

Comment: I’m wondering if the reason could be that there aren’t any directories like that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because more information was requested (about the existence of the indicated directories), but user failed to provide this.

Answer (score 0):

The cron utility runs commands in a different environment than your shell environment and may even be using a different shell than your default shell. To see what your cron environment looks like you can use the `env` command, e.g. add the following crontab for a minute:

```
* * * * * env > ~/cronenv
```

After a minute passes inspect the `~/cronenv` file to see the cron environment (taken from [How to simulate the environment cron executes a script with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with)). You can compare that to your shell environment to help debug the cron-related error. You can also run the script yourself using the cron environment:

```bsh
env - `cat ~/cronenv` /bin/sh
```

You might also try modifying your script for the purposes of debugging:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -ld /home/*
ls -ld /home/*/domains/*
find /home/*/domains/*/public_html/  -name "*.php" -mtime -1 | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Run that as a cronjob and see if you get the same error using a different command (e.g. the `ls` command).

Comment: The difference in environment does not explain why the glob does not expand.